# Removing Duplicate Items in an Array without Regex or filter

Tags: javascript

I have been stumped on this problem for a few hours now and am making no progress.  I feel like this should be simple.  I am trying to Remove duplicate characters in a String without using methods such as Filter or a Reg ex.

Here is my current code:

```
var duplicate = function(string) {
  var newString = string.split("");
  var finalArrayWithNoDuplicates = []

  for (var i = 0; i < newString.length; i++){
    for (var=0; j < newString.length; i++){
      while(newString[i])
        if (newString[i] !== newString[j]){

        }
    }
  }

  return finalArrayWithNoDuplicates.join("");

};
```

I am able to filter one letter at a time but as I progress down the chain in the while statement I am adding letters that were filtered out originally.

All of the algorithm tutorials for this algorithm are in Java that I have been finding.  Is there a way to do this with only using a a for and while loops?

Comment: So you're trying to remove duplicate characters from a string, or are you actually trying to remove duplicate array values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the proposed code:

- It has serious errors (the inner loop is written all wrong)
- You don't need to involve arrays at all, strings will do just fine
- The "if char !== other char" check will never provide enough information to act on

Here's an alternative version using for loops and the same basic idea:

```
function deduplicate(str) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        var found = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (str[i] == str[j]) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) result += str[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Each character `str[i]` in the input string is compared to all characters `str[j]` that precede it (there is no point in comparing to characters that follow it because we are going to process those when their turn comes up anyway). If the character is not equal to any of those that precede it then we know it's the first of its kind to appear and include it in the result.

Note that this algorithm has O(n²) performance, which is very poor compared to other possible approaches. Its main selling point is that it is straightforward and that everything happens "in front of your eyes".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of your function that uses an object to keep track of which letters have already been encountered:

```
var duplicate = function(string) {
  var finalArrayWithNoDuplicates = [];
  var seen = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (!seen[string[i]]) {
      finalArrayWithNoDuplicates.push(string[i]);
      seen[string[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  return finalArrayWithNoDuplicates.join("");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No need for two nested for-loops
2. No need for "while" loop as well
3. in the following line of code there are two errors: `for (var=0; j < newString.length; i++){` first one is `var=0` (compilation error) and second is theat you increment `i` instead of `j`
4. It can be done by adding only unique elements (that don't appear twice) to `finalArrayWithNoDuplicates`

as follows:

```
var duplicate = function(newString) {

  var finalArrayWithNoDuplicates = []
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < newString.length; i++){
        // if the char appears in another index 
        // or if it's already in the result - don't add it
    if (newString.lastIndexOf(newString[i]) !== i || finalArrayWithNoDuplicates.indexOf(newString[i]) > -1){
            continue;
    }
    else{
      finalArrayWithNoDuplicates[x++] = newString[i];
    }

  }

  return finalArrayWithNoDuplicates.join("");

};

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7];
alert(duplicate(arr));
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 1234567